# Python, VSC: How to correctly import a file into my code

Tags: python, import, module

I'm a college student who is fairly new to both Python and VSC and am experimenting with creating my own MadLibs program. I have my main file that asks the user which story they would like, and depending on their answer, imports the correct story.
Here is my main code:

```
#Mad Libs
#5/4/2022

num = int(input('Input a number 1-9 to choose a story!'))

if num == 1:
    import MadLibs1
    MadLibs1.story1
```

And here is my MadLibs1 code (shortened):

```
def story1():
    verb1 = str(input('Enter an ing-verb: '))
    place1 = str(input('Enter a physical location: '))
    holiday_song = str(input('Enter a holiday song: '))
 
    story = f'HOLIDAY MADNESS \n \nI was {verb1} at the {place1} the other day \
    when I heard {holiday_song} come on the radio.\n\
    print(story)
    print('')
```

MadLibs1 is another python file I have, and story1 is a function that takes nouns, verbs, etc. and prints the revised mad libs story.
My problem: when I run the program, it correctly asks me to input a number. When I  input the number and press Enter, the following shows up:

```
PS C:\Users\joshu\OneDrive - University of Missouri\Documents\Python files VSC\Mad Libs>
```

And it expects me to provide an input. I'm not sure why it's wanting another input. It's just supposed to go straight to executing the function that is in MadLibs1.

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Josh

Comment: You should also post content of the `MadLibs1` file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Alrighty, edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import a file you need to import **with** the file extension. For example...

```
import filename.py
```

**EDIT**

In the MadLibs file you need to actually call the function. All you have done is declare the function. You call a function by typing the function name with parentheses and any required arguments. This needs to be done **underneath** the declared function like this

```
story ()
```